# Comparing plots question

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a program that randomly generates line plots and what I would like to do now is compare two of those line plots and get a measure of 'similarity' between them. Now I feel as if this measure of similarity is relative to other measures I'm taking; correct me if I'm wrong. So is there any theorem/algorithm that can do this? If not, any that will get me closer to what I want?

Comment: please undo your edit and ask your new question separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S(1)=\sum_{n=1}^{2014} x_n$. Now, for $n \in \{1,2,...,2014\}$ we have $x_{2014+n}<x_{2014}x_n$. Hence,

$S(2)=\sum_{n=1}^{4028} x_n < S(1)+a^{2014}S(1)$.

Now $x_{4028} < {x_{2014}}^2=a^{4028}$, and for $n \in \{1,2,...,2014\}$ we have $x_{4028+n}<x_{4028}x_n$. Hence,

$S(3)=\sum_{n=1}^{6042} x_n < S(1)+a^{2014}S(1)+a^{4028}S(1)$.

Now, again $x_{6042}<x_{4028}x_{2014}<a^{6042}$.

Repeating the process to infinity, we get that:

$$\displaystyle S(\infty)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}S(1)a^{2014n}=S(1)+a^{2014}S(1)+a^{4028}S(1)+...$$

Using the fact that $S(1)$ is a real number, we have a geometric series that converges to $$\frac{S(1)}{1-a^{2014}}$$

Now $\displaystyle y_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n$ is an increasing sequence which is bounded above by $S(\infty)$, so converges.